# Scikit-learn: error in replacing missing data

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying to preprocess my data by replacing the missing value by the mean.

My code is as follows:

```
#Load the Data 
import numpy as np
data_2 = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1)

#the missing values in my dataset are identified by value = 0 
#I'm trying to replace the missing values in the third column 
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
imp = Imputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit(data_2[:, 2])
```

it runs but gave these warnings:

```
/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)

/Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)
```

but my main problem is that it did not fill the missing data, I printed the data before and after the fitting and no change.

What's the thing I'm doing wrong?

Update: 
Here is few lines of my dataset: 
6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1 
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0 
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1 
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0

Comment: Can you share a few lines of data.csv?

Comment: you fit the imputer only on the second column `imp.fit(data_2[:, 2])`.  Can this be your problem ? the column may not have zeros after all ...

Comment: It has zero values I am sure of that ..

Answer (score 1):

- The first few lines you shared doesn't contain any null values, so becomes difficult to explain
- Consider this slightly updated version of your dataset to make you understand.

  ```
  6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
  1,85,,29,0,26.6,0.351,,
  ,183,64,,0,,0.672,32,1
  1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
  ```
- There is an easy way around filling missing values by using the library pandas

  ```
  #Load Libraries and data
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

  #Fill the Null values with the mean
  df = df.fillna(df.mean())
  ```
- **names** argument in **read_csv** function is used to give name to the columns of the csv file
- **fillna()** function will fill the missing values.

Comment: The problem is in my dataset the zeros are equivalent to NaN so calculating the mean directly and filling the missing values is not correct .. i.e. assume I have the following values [0,3 ,4, 5, 0 ,1] if I calculate the mean while counting the zeros =  2.167 , without them = 3.25 so a simple mean calculation is not correct .. same goes if I were to use the median

Comment: So, what is the mean value you want for [0,3 ,4, 5, 0 ,1]